# Custom session timeout handler

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am using **spring security 3** and i have the session timeout set to 30 minutes, and when session timeouts the user is redirected to login page.

what i want to do is to implement a solution that if the user is in a specific page (**/page/specific_page**) the user gets redirected to specific page (**/page/anotherloginpage**) other than login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `Session Management` with `invalid-session-url` will help you http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt.

Comment: there's a difference between invalid and expired.

Comment: Have you read this: >Note that if you use this mechanism to detect session timeouts, it may falsely report an error if the user logs out and then logs back in without closing the browser. This is because the session cookie is not cleared when you invalidate the session and will be resubmitted even if the user has logged out.